# Specific piecewise-function SAT2 question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Taken from Barron's SAT Math Level 2 prep book:

If f(x) = i, where i is an integer such that i ≤ x < i + 1, the range of f(x) is

```
       (A)  the set of all real numbers
       (B)  the set of all positive integers
       (C)  the set of all integers
       (D)  the set of all negative integers
       (E)  the set of all nonnegative real numbers
```

Here's how I tried to solve it:  *i* has to be an integer, which eliminates answer choices A and E. I then tried to manipulate the inequality to focus it on *i*:

i ≤ x

AND

x < i + 1

x - 1 < i

therefore:

x - 1 < i ≤ x

Now there are no constraints on our x so whatever its value is, *i* is going to be an integer less than or equal to x and more than x-1, which led me to answer choice C.
The correct answer according to Barrons is D. I can't think of a reason why *i* has to be a negative integer.

So why is it so and is there a better way of solving it (using a graphic calculator is allowed.)?

**EDIT:** I apologize. Just checked a newer edition and apparently this is a typo and should be C. Sorry.

Comment: $f$ is a very well known function (especially to computer science students). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1\le 1.1<2$ so $f(1.1)=1$ while $-2\le -1.1<-1$ so $f(-1.1)=-2$.

Looks like (C) to me with what we were given.